# argumentsはどこに所属している？

Tags: javascript

**arguments はどこに所属しているのでしょうか？**

- Built-in objects ではなく、Function プロパティでもなく、全く別の独立した存在？

最初は、Built-in objects かな、と思い探したのですが、見つかりませんでした。
以下のページに下記記載があるのですが、これはどういう意味でしょうか？

> Function のプロパティとしての arguments はもはや使用されません

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

- argumentsオブジェクトは、Function プロパティとして使用していないから、Function プロパティではない？ どこか別の所属？
- argumentsオブジェクトは、Function プロパティとして使用していないが、Function プロパティに所属している？
- 使用していないことと、所属の有無には、相関関係があるのでしょうか？
- そもそも、「プロパティとして使用されません」とは、どういう意味でしょうか？
- 使用可能だけど、非推奨ってこと？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`arguments`は、実行コンテキストに属します。ローカル変数と同じイメージです。

関数オブジェクトを実行している間、その関数オブジェクトの`arguments`プロパティとしても`arguments`にアクセスすることができます。このプロパティは、関数が実行されていない間は`null`です (実行コンテキストが無いため)。

```
function foo() {
  console.log(arguments == foo.arguments);
}

foo(1, 2, 3); // true
console.log(foo.arguments); // null
```

関数オブジェクトの `arguments` プロパティは、将来的に削除されます。現在 Strict モードで関数オブジェクトの `arguments` プロパティにアクセスすると、`TypeError`がスローされます。

```
function foo() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(foo.arguments);
}

foo(1, 2, 3); // TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
```

Answer (score 1):

> Function のプロパティとしての arguments はもはや使用されません

とは非標準のFunction.prototype.argumentsは使うなということです。

```
function fn () {
  return arguments == fn.arguments
  // 同じものだが後者は使わず前者を使う
}
fn()  // true
```